# PowerBI.com Dataset Refresh for Azure Data Lake with OAuth2

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, powerbi, azure-data-lake, powerbi-datasource

**Situation:** I have a Power BI desktop workbook with a data source connection to Azure Data Lake storage. I can query the storage and get to the datasets without any problem. I've created my visuals and published the workbook to PowerBI.com.

**Next:** I want to schedule the refresh of the dataset so the reports hit my Azure Data Lake files and get updated. However the OAuth2 popup and dialogue don't seem to work and after completing the login prompts I just get an endless spinning circle that never returns. As below.

[image]

**Additional things:** I've followed several different sets of instructions to register a new app in my Azure AD, granting it PowerBI API services. Assigning the app permissions to the storage etc. But without success. Tried native and web/API apps. Instructions here...

https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-developer-authenticate-a-client-app/

I've testing using various URLs for the data lake storage as my Power BI workbook source. Including ADL://... webhdfs://... and https://... All result in the same situation.

I can confirm my Power BI logins are my Microsoft "Work" accounts. As is my Azure Data Lake storage all connected up correctly with Office 365 and Azure AD.

**Questions:** What am I missing? I wish there was even an error message to work from. But it gives me nothing. If this were a .Net app giving it the client ID etc would make sense. But Power BI.com just asks for my login details.

Does the Power BI preview connector for Azure Data Lake even work once published to PowerBI.com? I can't find any example out there of anybody else doing this.

Many thanks for your time and assistance friends.

Comment: Sorry about the issue you are facing. Have you tried publishing a PBIX file with a simple query, to PBI.com that will access files from ADLS? It is also not clear what credentials you are using when using PBI desktop and when you are logged into PBI.com. Are they the same? Thanks,
Sachin Sheth
Program Manager, Azure Data Lake team.

Comment: Hi Sachin, thanks for the reply. Yes, I have tested this with a very small simple Power BI workbook. When I click 'Sign In' in the above screen shot I provide my credentials that have access to the ADLS. The same credentials also have access to Power BI as our Azure subscription, Office 365 and on prem domains are all linked. Thanks

Comment: Hi Paul, Let me reach out to some internal team members about the issue and see what we can do about it.

Comment: Can you please retry? Looks like there was a wider issue that was causing this and has since been resolved. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Hi Paul. Did you manage to resolve described problem? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: Sadly not, but I've since written a more detailed blog post about the exact problem having investigated it further, link below, and also raised it with Microsoft via several different avenues. https://www.purplefrogsystems.com/paul/2017/06/connecting-power-bi-to-azure-data-lake-store-across-tenants/

Comment: Please also vote for this issue to be resolved here: https://office365.uservoice.com/forums/264636-general/suggestions/17841250-allow-powerbi-com-to-connect-directly-to-azure-dat

Comment: Thanks, I've just voted.